# How to ensure unique with non-domain Command class using @Validateable in Grails

Tags: grails, spring-validator

I have the following...

```
@Validateable
class Command1{
  List<Command2> subCommands
}

@Validateable
class Command2{
  String name
  Long id
}
```

Now I want to create a constraint to ensure the items in subCommands have a unique name. What should my constraint look like? Should it be on Command1 or Command2?

Comment: Have you tried a custom constraint yet?

Comment: I played around with it but I can't seem to figure out the right way to create it. I know I can be pretty dense sometimes :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since `Command2` doesn't know about `Command1`, you have to put your constraint on `Command1`. You can accomplish this with a custom constraint, since the [`unique`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/unique.html) constraint checks at the database level and is only applicable for domain objects.

```
@Validateable
class Command1{
    List<Command2> subCommands

    static constraints = {
        subCommands validator: { val ->
            val.unique(false) { it.name } == val
        }
    }
}
```

Tested in a Groovy shell but not in Grails:

```
list = [[name: 'foo'], [name: 'bar'], [name: 'baz']]
assert list.unique(false) { it.name } == list
list = [[name: 'foo'], [name: 'bar'], [name: 'bar']]
assert list.unique(false) { it.name } != list
```

Passing `false` to [`unique()`](http://beta.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#unique%28boolean,%20groovy.lang.Closure%29) tells it to not mutate the list in-place.